# I Have Three Colors: A "What Am I" Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here is the riddle:

```
I have three colors,
each with a different meaning.
When I'm old they become dull,
but when I'm new they are gleaming.

I help keep people safe,
but sometimes they hate me.
You won't see me in a forest,
but you will in a big city.

Some of me have short lengths,
and some of me have long.
And in the time that the longest of me take,
you could sing a very long song.

When my colors change,
people get happy or sad,
and when you guess what I am,
you will be very glad!
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> a traffic light.

I have three colors,

> Red, yellow, and green

each with a different meaning.

> Red is a no-go, yellow is to prepare, and green is go.

When I'm old they become dull,

> Excessive sunlight make the color-coating of the traffic lights fade, or alternatively the light bulbs can lose their strength.

but when I'm new they are gleaming.

> Shiny new lights are nicely visible.

I help keep people safe,

> Traffic lights keep you in order.

but sometimes they hate me.

> You don't like to wait when it is red.

You won't see me in a forest,

> Hardly.

but you will in a big city.

> Indeed, at major traffic junctions.

Some of me have short lengths,
and some of me have long.
And in the time that the longest of me take,
you could sing a very long song.

> The time of changing color depends from place-to-place, and also from color-to-color. Red takes forever!

When my colors change,
people get happy or sad,

> Time to start your car!

and when you guess what I am,
you will be very glad!

> Indeed. Although I would not be surprised, if this would be a duplicate. We should go and check.

Comment: `you will be very glad!` I think "glad" does not exactly fit here...

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> Stop light.

The three colors are

> green, yellow and red. Green means you can go, yellow means to proceed with caution, and red means stop.

You keep people safe

> by controlling the flow of traffic.

But some people hate

> to be stuck at a red light, especially if it's a long one.
>  There are no stop lights in a forest, only in a city.
>  There is no standard length of time for a light to change. Some of them can take a very long time.
>  People are happy when they have the green light to go, sad when they have to wait at a red light.